# Search for a specific character in a 2D array

Tags: c, search, multidimensional-array

I was wondering how you would search through a 2D array (used as a parameter for a function), and find a specific character, e.g. an exclamation mark?

Say I have a 2D array island[20][40] and I want to find the character X. My approach would be to use a nested for loop, to go through each element and an if statement. E.g.

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 40; j++) {
    //Not sure what goes here (I want a function that identifies the element in the array)
    if ((some variable) == 88)
    printf("The treasure is at: (%d, %d)", i, j);
```

Thanks for your help :)

-island[20][40] works fine. I just want to know how to search through it for a specific character.

Comment: Do you ask this already knowing how to do it with a 1D array?

Comment: is `island[i][j]` not working? What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the condition

```
 if (island[i][j] == 88);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array(s) are not ordered then you have no choice but to search through sequentially, there are no short cut.